# This function becomes undefined and I don't know why

Tags: javascript, postgresql, function, ejs

I am trying to make a program using javascript, EJS, and SQL(PostgreSQL) but I am having an issue that crashes my server making me unable to go further.

.query(`SELECT * FROM public.games WHERE id= ${highscore.gameid}`)
^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'gameid')

Here is my error

I have tried to delete data from my database and tried to change this function I also tried to remove it but it just messed up my code even more. Also weirdly enough, my code worked, but the next day I got this error.

```
const getHighscore = async (id) => {
  let highscore;
  const pool = new Pool(credentials);

  await pool
    .query(`SELECT * FROM public.highscores WHERE id= ${id}`)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.rows[0]);
      highscore = res.rows[0];
    });
  await pool
    .query(`SELECT * FROM public.games WHERE id= ${highscore.gameid}`)
    .then((res) => (highscore.game = res.rows[0]));

  return highscore;
};

Console.log(res.row[0]) = undefined

Console.log(res) = Result {
  command: 'SELECT',
  rowCount: 0,
  oid: null,
  rows: [],
  fields: [
    Field {
      name: 'id',
      tableID: 24601,
      columnID: 1,
      dataTypeID: 23,
      dataTypeSize: 4,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      format: 'text'
    },
    Field {
      name: 'username',
      tableID: 24601,
      columnID: 2,
      dataTypeID: 1043,
      dataTypeSize: -1,
      dataTypeModifier: 34,
      format: 'text'
    },
    Field {
      name: 'gameid',
      tableID: 24601,
      columnID: 3,
      dataTypeID: 23,
      dataTypeSize: 4,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      format: 'text'
    },
    Field {
      name: 'score',
      tableID: 24601,
      columnID: 4,
      dataTypeID: 23,
      dataTypeSize: 4,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      format: 'text'
    },
    Field {
      name: 'active',
      tableID: 24601,
      columnID: 5,
      dataTypeID: 16,
      dataTypeSize: 1,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      format: 'text'
    },
    Field {
      name: 'date',
      tableID: 24601,
      columnID: 6,
      dataTypeID: 1082,
      dataTypeSize: 4,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      format: 'text'
    }
  ],
  _parsers: [
    [Function: parseInteger],
    [Function: noParse],
    [Function: parseInteger],
    [Function: parseInteger],
    [Function: parseBool],
    [Function: parseDate]
  ],
  _types: TypeOverrides {
    _types: {
      getTypeParser: [Function: getTypeParser],
      setTypeParser: [Function: setTypeParser],
      arrayParser: [Object],
      builtins: [Object]
    },
    text: {},
    binary: {}
  },
  RowCtor: null,
  rowAsArray: false
}
```

Comment: your code is open to SQL injection. You should use a prepared statement with parameters.

Comment: Well This is just for me I am not gonna put this online so don't need to worry about SQL injections

Comment: You should still learn the proper way to code. It will also avoid some common syntax errors, like if you forget to quote a string.

Comment: can you add logs for console.log(res.rows[0]); in the post?

Comment: I have added both  console.log(res.rows[0]); and console.log(res)

Comment: so you should use res.fields instead of res.rows

Comment: doesn't look like using 'res.fields' would work here. Using res.fields[0] would return a Field object which doesn't have a 'gameid' property which is accessed in the second query. It might prevent getting an TypeError (since highscore won't be undefined) but behavior might not be as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your logs the error seems to be as expected. You're setting `highscore` to `res.rows[0]`, which is *undefined*. Therefore, no `gameid` property exists on `highscore`, hence the error.

If `res.rows` is what's supposed to contain your data, then basically right now you're not getting back the needed data or it doesn't exist.

A better approach might be to make this query ONLY if `highscore` is NOT undefined or null, and the `gameid` property exists:

```
if (highscore && highscore.hasOwnProperty('gameid'))
 await pool
    .query(`SELECT * FROM public.games WHERE id= ${highscore.gameid}`)
    .then((res) => (highscore.game = res.rows[0]));
```

Remember though, `highscore` will still get returned even if it is *undefined*, so your function might return *undefined*

You could also use optional chaining instead

```
`SELECT * FROM public.games WHERE id= ${highscore?.gameid}`
```

Doing this will avoid error because of `highscore` being undefined, but it will be an unnecessary call to *query*

Hope it helps.